# Hadoop and video data

Tags: video, hadoop

Hadoop is perfect for storing large data that is not accessed in real time and can grow on commodity hardware. Is there an alternative or some system built on top of it that can store a lot of video files (example: .flv) that can be retrieved and shown similar to youtube/vimeo? I like Hadoop's ability to not rely on expensive hardware and having a lot of copies. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that reason most appropriate solution is HBase which use Hadoop file system, and can quickly retrieve any binary data from store by key (id/name etc)

Comment: Thanks.I have looked at HBase before but I read that Hbase is good for storing image like files, and for files bigger than 10MB - you again need to use HDFS.I am not sure here if I want to put 700MB file and stream it - would I still use HBase on top of Hadoop or?